# Why does CSS mix-blend-mode "darken" produce a different result than Photoshop?

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

As far as I understand, CSS' `mix-blend-mode` is supposed to behave the same way as Photoshop' Blend mode. However, in the following simple example I am getting different results and I am not sure why.

**Example**

A cyan rectangle (#00ffff) half overlapping a red rectangle (#ff0000). The blend mode of the cyan rectangle is set to "darken". Because "darken" picks the darkest of each channel (RGB) for the overlapping pixels, and all three channels are 0 in at least one of the two rectangles, I would expect the overlapping area to be black.

**Result in Photoshop**

(cyan rectangle outlined for clarity)

- The cyan rectangle is not visible on the black background (expected)
- The overlapping area is also black (expected)

[image]

**Result on web (Latest Chrome, 70.0.3538.102)**

- The cyan rectangle is visible on the black background (not expected)
- The overlapping area is dark (#2d0c1b), but not black (not expected)

[image]

Live example: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/walmink/pen/WYZNOW)

So... why is the result not the same? What am I missing?

Comment: the overlay seems black to me, probably it's your screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is the same but the black background is applied to the `body` and not the to parent of the element where you applied the `mix-blend-mode`.

Moving the black background there will fix the issue:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.group {
 background:#000;
}
.a, .b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background: #00ffff;
}

.b {
  background: #ff0000;
  margin-top: -50px;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

> The mix-blend-mode CSS property sets how an element's content should **blend with the content of the element's parent** and the element's background.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That explains why the non-overlapping part of the cyan rectangle was shown in my CodePen example. However, it still doesn't explain why the overlapping area appears as #2D0C1B instead of pure black (#000)?

Comment: @Walmink in my case it's pure black, it's probably related to some settings of your screen?

Comment: I tried in Firefox and got black as well. Then I played with the colour calibration on my MacBookPro and noticed that the "sRGB" and "Color LCD-1" also produced the right blending effect in Safari and Chrome. Looks like those two were respecting a colour profile I had set up in the past. Thank for helping to find the root cause!

Comment: P.S. Maybe add the colour profile hint to your answer for future reference? Thank you :)

Comment: @Walmink I upvoted your comment so it's a part of the answer and people will check it;)